# what's the difference between devMiddleware.publicPath and static.publicPath

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-4, webpack-5

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md

was reading this and noticed that you can use publicPath 2 ways. I'm not sure what the difference is.